# What authentication methods are supported by MacOS's WebDav client in Finder?

Tags: macos, authentication, webdav

The native WebDav client accessible from Finder on MacOS supports Basic Authentication.

Are other authentication methods supported such as Oauth or SAML, and if so, what are they?